# How to test tilt effect in iphone simulator?

Tags: ios, simulator, iphone-developer-program, tilt

I am currently making an ios game in a program called [istencyl](http://www.stencyl.com/stencylworks/istencyl/) for a contest on there website. The game involves rolling a character around with the accelerometer. Everything would be going fine but unfortunately in the ios simulator you can't test tilt! I would test it on my device but I'm 13 and I don't have the money to buy a dev kit, meaning I can't test it on a device. I saw something on here about using a subclass UIAccelerometer but I'm not a good programmer (istencyl lets you use either a block system or regular code, i chose the blocks) so I didn't understand it. Istencyl programs with a gui usually but you can do the coding yourself I'm just not sure how. Any ideas? I heard about this one app on the app store called [iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) but its 16 dollars! Is it worth it?

Comment: Wellcome to StackOverflow and congratulations - even though you are still relatively young, you still had no difficulties in telling us what you are indenting and why it did not work. Awesome!

Comment: Thanks! I hate to bother you, but do you know how to fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: No, I am sorry - I do not know if iSimulate would help for your project - I have never used or heard of it. For my work, I have learned to live with the fact that the simulator does not support most "physical" sensors.

Comment: You cannot use the simulator for testing things related to UIAccelerometer, but there is one thing you can do! It does not meet Apple's policy, but you can make a fake code sign in Xcode, and use it to build and run apps on a real device. However if you want to continue developing for iOS, you have to have a dev account. Good luck! :)